# Is there any reason to prefer signed or unsigned integers to represent lists of bits?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Is there any reason to prefer signed or unsigned integers over the other to represent lists of bits?

I believe people tend to use `unsigned` for this more: for example, C++'s `bitset` converts to and from `unsigned long`.

Is this an arbitrary decision, or is `unsigned` better?

Comment: `unsigned` is guaranteed to be able to hold any combination of bits.  `signed` is not; it can have padding or trap representations.

Comment: `signed` also doesn't play well with the shift operators, which you often want when dealing with bit strings.

Comment: Unsigned is also helpful in guaranteeing the results of overflows.

Comment: @NateEldredge `signed also doesn't play well with the shift operators` -- this is what I'm asking about. How? When?..

Comment: @MaxB  Read the section __Bitwise shift operators__ lots of _"...For signed and non-negative...otherwise the behavior is undefined..."_ and Standard Changes - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Let's take a right shift as an example.  The rightmost bit is shifted out into the ether.  Now the question is: what is shifted into the leftmost bit?  Is a 1 shifted in or is a zero shifted in?  Hmmm.  With *unsigned*, a zero is shifted in.  In assembly language, you have the option of also shifting in the "carry" bit.  Interesting.  This is important because in 2's compliment, the leftmost bit is the "sign" bit for signed integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an unsigned type for integers representing bits is preferred.  You'll often use the bit shift operators `<<` and `>>` on these integers, and these operators have well defined behavior on unsigned integers (provided you don't shift more than the number of bits or by a negative amount).

If you use `<<` and `>>` on signed integers, the former has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you shift bits with value 1 into or out of the sign bit, and the latter has implementation defined behavior for negative values.

Section 6.5.7 p4 and p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) spells this out:

> *4* The  result  of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit  positions;  vacated  bits  are  filled  with zeros.  IfE1has  an
> unsigned  type,  the  value  of  the  result  is E1×2<sup>E2</sup>,
> reduced  modulo one  more  than  the  maximum  value  representable
> in  the  result  type.  If `E1` has  a  signedtype  and  nonnegative
> value,  and E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is  representable  in  the  result
> type,  then  that  is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.
>
> *5* The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions.  If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a
> nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part  of
> the  quotient  of E1/2<sup>E2</sup>. If `E1` has  a  signed  type  and
> a  negative  value,  the resulting value is implementation-defined.

One thing you need to watch out for however is using unsigned types that are smaller than `int`.  This is because values of those types will be promoted to `int` when being used in a expression.